# get first 3 occurrence of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-retrieval

In my rails app I have below code to print some data from database.

```
<% @di.each do |d| %>
  <% if d["visibility_team"] == 'for_all' %>
   //my code goes here
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I just want to print first 3 occurrence which fulfill the **d["visibility_team"] == 'for_all'** condition.

How can I do this?

Comment: how are you getting your @di active records?

Comment: if you're only needing visibilty_team = 'for_all' you can put in your active record a condition @di = Di.where("visibilty_team = 'for_all'").limit(3). Replacle "Di" for your model. And you also need to put an order condition depending on what column do you consider "first" occurrences

Comment: @AbdelP.I want to use this within my .erb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get `@di` as 3 records from DB, how about keeping counter how many `d`s were printed?

Something like this (feel free to style it the way you want)

```
<% counter = 0 %>
<% @di.each do |d| %>
  <% if d["visibility_team"] == 'for_all' %>
     <% counter += 1 %>
     <% break if counter == 3 %>
   //your code goes here
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However it's usually a bad taste to have so much logic in views.